# Yii2 mp3 upload does not work for some users

Tags: php, upload, yii2, mp3

I created a website where artists can upload songs and pictures. For most people everything works fine, bute somethimes a user gets the following error:

"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, service@webmailer.de and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

maybe it's a problem of the server ? at the error log i can't find something, there are no entrys at this time.

the code is this ffor the controller action:

```
$musiker = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
                $songgenre = $model->songgenre;

                $model->song = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'song');
                $dateiname = 'songs/'.$musiker.''.time().'.'.$model->song->extension;
                $model->song->saveAs($dateiname);
                $model->saveSong($musiker, $songname, $songgenre, $dateiname);
```

and the form which i use for upload:

```
//Song hochladen    
    echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";
        echo "<div class=' col-md-12'>";
            $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]);     
            echo $form->field($model,'song')->fileInput()->label(false);
            echo $form->field($model, 'songname');
            echo $form->field($model, 'songgenre')-> listBox(array('Wave'=>'Wave','Rock'=>'Rock','Pop'=>'Pop','Metal'=>'Metal','Punk'=>'Punk','Schlager'=>'Schlager', 'Elektro'=>'Elektro'))->label(false);  
            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                echo "<input type='submit' name = 'song' class='btn  btn-primary' onClick='load()' value='hinzufügen'/>";

            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        ActiveForm::end();
```

has someone any idea where the problem could be ?

Comment: Sorry, but an "internal error (http 500)" will _certainly_ create an entry in the http servers error log file, except if you disabled logging which one certainly should not do.

Comment: Check if you can write in the folder where the uploads are stored. Maybe you have a file permission problem. If you have apache the server log is under /var/log/apache/error.log.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I always checked the file permissions, as i said, for 30 users it works without problems but 2 hase this problem. One of them wrote me today that he used an old notebook which takes long time for the upload, today with a new one it works...  Maybe the server can't handle long upload times ?